# JSON loop not working

Tags: javascript, json, loops, each

I an trying to loop an javascript object, but i cant get it running. The data is comming form the localStorage.

my output:

```
 {"widget": {"title": "blablabla", "color": "yellow"},"widget": {"title": "lorem ipsum", "color": "black"},......}
```

// what i have tried(the key works)

```
var list = JSON.parse(the localStoragekey);

for(var key in list){
if (list.hasOwnProperty(key)){  
       console.log(list[key])
    }
}
```

I have looked on the web(and Stackoverflow) but i cant seem to find a working solution.

Comment: well to be honest i am a noob, so i can have it wrong ;)

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried, the code that you wrote that is not working and what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: i have included the code that i have used

Answer (score 5):

You have duplicate keys in your object.  Use an array instead.

```
var widgets = [
    {"title": "blablabla", "color": "yellow"},
    {"title": "lorem ipsum", "color": "black"}
]
```